# MySQL - Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: mysql

Can someone please tell me what exactly is wrong with this MySQL statement?

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tempdelv6
 CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempdelv6 (
      'despatchmethod' VARCHAR(50),
      'tracking' int,
      'refCount' int
    )
```

This is the response I get when the above is executed:

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempdelv6 (       'despatchmethod' VARCHAR(50),       'tr' at line 2

VERSION: 5.7.23-0ubuntu0.16.04.1

Comment: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tempdelv6;  put a semicolon in the end, for more info https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/drop-table.html

Comment: Missed ; after drop table.

Comment: Sorry, but none of these suggestions work, I had already tried this

Comment: If I fix the DROP (with the semi-colon) statement or even remove it, I get the following response:

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''despatchmethod' VARCHAR(50), 'tracking' int, 'refCount' int )' at line 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the missing terminators you are using single quotes instead of backtick'

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tempdelv6;
 CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempdelv6(
      `despatchmethod` VARCHAR(50),
      `tracking` int,
      `refCount` int
    );
```

Comment: Thank you! thats what it was!

Answer (score 2):

Add a semicolon end of the first line. And remove the single quotes

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tempdelv6;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempdelv6 (
  despatchmethod VARCHAR(50),
  tracking int,
  refCount int
)
```

Comment: Thanks Ntwobike, but I get a simliar response:
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''despatchmethod' VARCHAR(50),   'tracking' int,   'refCount' int )' at line 2

Comment: You missed the single quotes.